# How to Add Values in Ajax or Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have POS system made in codigniter. I have three fields

1. Cash Received
2. Cash Pending
3. Balance

I have payment edit form that open in a model and display values. I am getting values with these code

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'payment/editPaymentByJason?id=' + iid,
  method: 'GET',
  data: '',
  dataType: 'json',
}).success(function (response) {
  var cr = response.cash_received;        
  var cp = response.cash_pending;        
  var b = cr - cp;
```

but the output is not what i need. Let suppose

```
Cash Received = 500
Cash Pending = 200
```

Instead of showing 300 in the balance field This this function shows `500200` in the balance field.

I want to how i add or subtract value in var b ?

Comment: Convert to number using `parseInt()`/`parseFloat()` i.e `var cr = parseInt(response.cash_received, 10); `

Comment: you need convert it before subtract using parseInt

Comment: Thanks alot friends i got what i want using var b = parseInt(cr) - parseInt(cp);

Answer (score 0):

You can only make calculations with number values.

`cr` and `cp` are probably strings, so you need to convert them with `parseInt()` or `parseFloat` (when you want to use decimal values).

Comment: Thanks alot friends i got what i want using
var balance = parseInt(cr) - parseInt(cp);